# Is there a way to distinguish app being started by Launch Services at login or by user?

Tags: macos, cocoa, startup, launch-services

Cocoa app can add themselves to  `LSSharedFileList`'s list of login items. This will allow application to be started when user logs in. However, is there a way to tell whether user started the application or the app auto-started at login? This is useful because in one case we can show a user interface in another we can hide the UI and run the app in background as a menubar app.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code for this. I'm not sure what it returns for login items, but if you try it out and comment I'll update the post. It does return `com.apple.Finder` for Finder and `com.apple.dt.Xcode` for Xcode.

```
+ (NSString *) bundleIdentifierOfParentProcess {
    NSString *result = nil;
    ProcessSerialNumber psn = {0, 0};
    if (0 == GetCurrentProcess(&psn)) {
        ProcessInfoRec myProcessInfo;
        myProcessInfo.processInfoLength = sizeof(ProcessInfoRec);
        myProcessInfo.processName = NULL;
        myProcessInfo.processAppRef = NULL;
        if (0 == GetProcessInformation(&psn, &myProcessInfo)) {
            ProcessSerialNumber parentPSN = myProcessInfo.processLauncher;
            CFDictionaryRef parentProcessInfo =
            ProcessInformationCopyDictionary(&parentPSN,
                                             kProcessDictionaryIncludeAllInformationMask);
            if (parentProcessInfo) {
                result =
                [(__bridge NSDictionary *) parentProcessInfo objectForKey:
                (__bridge id) kCFBundleIdentifierKey];
                CFRelease(parentProcessInfo);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

`parentProcessInfo` is a dictionary full of values which may also be helpful, in case the bundle identifier isn't meaningful enough.

Comment: the method is fine, but now in 2015 Apples CDO (Chief deprecation officer) has finally managed to deprecate `GetCurrentProcess` and `ProcessInformationCopyDictionary` and `GetProcessInformation`. He says we should use `NSRunningApplication` instead. Do you have any idea how this could possibly work?

Comment: Scanning the docs quickly, you could try `[[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:getppid()] bundleIdentifier]`.

Comment: no sorry, this does not work. That expression always evaluated to `nil` in the cases I tested: start as login item; start from Xcode; start through Finder. Each I tested at two places with the same result: in main(), and after -applicationDidFinishLaunching: