# How do I check if the app is started as a login item (or manually by the user)? On OS X 10.10

Tags: macos

I added my app as a login startup item. It appears in the list of startup items under System Preferences / Users & Groups / Login items.

When the app launches, how do I check wether it was launched as a login item or not?

I would like to do this with functions which are not deprecated. Otherwise, this is the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15395202/754705), only that most of the functions used there are deprecated by now.